# Proxy target property being set to proxy property counterpart

Tags: c#, properties, castle, proxy-classes, castle-dynamicproxy

Let's say I've the following code sample:

```
public class A 
{
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And I generate a proxy of `A`:

```
A aProxy = ... // Code to generate the whole proxy
aProxy.Text = "hello world";
```

Now I cast `aProxy` to gets its target:

```
IProxyTargetAccessor accessor = (IProxyTargetAccessor)aProxy;
A target = (A)aProxy.DynProxyGetTarget();
```

And I set `Text` on `target`:

```
target.Text = "bye!";
```

**I can't figure out why `aProxy` gets the whole property set too**. They should be different object instances, since one is the proxy which wraps the whole target, and the other is the target itself.

```
bool equal = target.Text == aProxy.Text; // TRUE: What's going on?
bool referenceEqual = ReferenceEquals(target, aProxy); // FALSE
```

Comment: You're leaving out a key piece of information: The proxy generation code.  There's lots of options for how the proxy is generated and that's probably affecting what you're seeing.  In a quick test, I got a `true` from my ReferenceEquals call.

Comment: @PatrickSteele Uhm you're right. I can add my proxy generation code. I'll do in some hours. BTW I can give you extra info: it's a proxy generation with target, with a mixin and a hook.

Comment: @PatrickSteele Now I've double-checked your comment... how the proxy and the whole target would be references to the same object? This shouldn't be happening too...

Comment: Why do you feel that shouldn't be happening?  I simply did `new ProxyGenerator().CreateClassProxy<A>()` and DP dynamically created and compiled a subclass of `A` that has all of the plumbing necessary for DP functionality. Part of that plumbing would be implementing `IProxyTargetAccessor.DynProxyGetTarget`.  And the implementation of that can simply return `this`.  Why would it return anything else?

Comment: @PatrickSteele Maybe I'm mistaken, but a class proxy with target (method `CreateClassProxyWithTarget`) creates a proxy which is a different instance than the target, but the whole proxy sets target's property counterpart. In the other hand, the target has no dependency with the proxy instance.

Comment: I don't think Dynamic Proxy works the way you think it does.  The proxy created is (in my mind) simply a pass-through; a "wrapper" around your target object.  It is meant to be transparent to consumers so they don't know (nor do they need to know) they're talking to a proxy.  If you have a reference to `target` and someone else has a reference to a proxy of `target`, they, in essence, have the actual `target` and, as you've seen, changes in the `target` are reflected through the proxy. Perhaps you could provide more context as to why you need the proxy to be standalone/disconnected.

Comment: @PatrickSteele I'm not sure about your conclusion... Changes on target can't be bound to proxy because the target is a POCO while the proxy binds its properties to the target so when you get the target of a given proxy, you get an object which has the exact property values of the proxy object, but it's *the POCO* again...

Comment: @PatrickSteele Uhm now I got the idea. Obviously, if the target is associated with the proxy, if you change the whole target properties outside of itself, the proxy will get the changes

Comment: @PatrickSteele So it seems that the answer is *Yes, it works this way* and the definitive solution is making a deep clone of the target to get my desired behavior.........